# Make GetListItems web service method ignore views entirely

Tags: list, web-services, list-view

The documentation for [GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) says that if a `viewName` is not specified, it will use the default view for the list. Is there any way to get all the list data regardless of what view is specified?

Edit - Here is the SOAP request being made following the suggestions in an answer, but this doesn't return all the row data:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <tns:GetListItems xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <tns:listName>{F54AF0C9-C473-433C-880A-EABB7625E3D6}</tns:listName>
      <tns:rowLimit>0</tns:rowLimit>
    </tns:GetListItems>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: You've got some namespacing going on (tns) that shouldn't be there. Look at /_vti_bin/lists.asmx?op=GetListItems to see what the packet should look like.

Answer (score 3):

You can break the connection with the default view by passing in any parameter. One easy one is to pass rowLimit = 0, which says to pass back all items. Or, you can use a query like

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <Gt>
         <FieldRef Name="ID" />
         <Value Type="Counter">0</Value>
      </Gt>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

which means to pass all items with a non-zero ID, which is all items.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm essentially calling: `GetListItems("{MyListGUID}", null, null, null, "0", null, null)` and getting the same trimmed results as if I called: `GetListItems("{MyListGUID}", "{MyDefaultViewGUID}", null, null, null, null, null)` (also tried the query option to no avail).

Comment: +1 for rowLimit=0. @user904 for a more specific answer you might want to show us your code.

Comment: @Christophe: It's being called from a Flex application with an auto-generated service layer, so the code might not be very useful. I'll update the question with the SOAP request that's being sent.